# Error when loading model file using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conda

I get this error for when I try to load a `.h5` file into a variable:

```
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Diplomski\faceVerify1.py", line 72, in <module>
model = load_model('facenet_keras.h5')

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
include_optimizer: If True, save optimizer's state together.

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 584, in load_model

  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 273, in _deserialize_model
if len(layer_names) != len(filtered_layers):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

After doing some reasearch I found out that the most likely reaosn for this is the mismatch or tensorflow, keras and h5py packages.

h5py as to be below 3.0.0 which I downgraded
And for tensorflow and keras versions I used this website that was shared in many other posts where people had this issue.
https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/environments/

I check in anaconda what my versions are and they are good:

```
tensorflow                1.14.0               h1f41ff6_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           1.14.0           py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.2.5                    py37_1    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0          nompi_py37he280515_106    conda-forge
```

SO I am kind of out of ideas. I check a lot of questions on stackoverflow and on the github forums, and matching the versions doesn't seem to work. The model `.h5` file I use is the standard face recog file I got from here :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12aMYASGCKvDdkygSv1yQq8ns03AStDO_

Comment: does it give you any other error? like file not found exception? where is your file 'facenet_keras.h5' located? in the same folder or in a sub folder?

Comment: @JeanCamargo its in the same folder as the script that is being run. paths aren't the issue. This is the only error and it happens at the load_model function. It loads images and everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by manually removing ever instance of "decode( " From the keras functions used to load the model.